# ¿Puedo usar un objeto como parametro cuando creo otro objeto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, clase, herencia

Mi consulta es la siguiente, si yo tengo una clase base **(Persona)** y hago un objeto con ella ¿Puedo utilizar los parametros del objeto para crear otro objeto con una clase heredada **(Empleado)** ?

```
class Persona():

    def __init__(self,nombre,edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad

    def imprimir_datos(self):

        print(f"{self.nombre}, {self.edad}")

class Empleado (Persona):

    def __init__(self,nombre,edad,sueldo):
        Persona.__init__(self,nombre,edad)
        self.sueldo = sueldo

    def debe_impuestos (self,self.nombre):

        if self.sueldo >= 3000:

            print(f"El empleado {self.nombre} tiene que pagar impuestos")

        else:

            print(f"El empleado {self.nombre} NO tiene que pagar impuestos")

per_osvaldo = Persona("Osvaldo",39)

per_osvaldo.imprimir_datos()

emplado_osvaldo = Empleado(per_osvaldo,3000)

emplado_osvaldo.debe_impuestos()
```

yo quiero que usar la linea:

```
emplado_osvaldo = Empleado(per_osvaldo,3000)
```

En vez de poner algo como:

```
emplado_osvaldo = Empleado("Osvaldo",39,3000)
```

¿Esto es posible?

Answer (score 1):

Por supuesto, al constructor de una clase puedes pasarle parámetros de cualquier tipo que estimes conveniente. Así que a tu constructor de `Empleado` puedes elgir pasarle un parámetro de tipo `Persona` en lugar de los dos parámetros `nombre` y `edad`.

No considero que esta idea vaya darte un código mejor o más fácil de usar, pero sería perfectamente posible, así:

```
class Empleado(Persona):
  def __init__(self, persona, sueldo):
      Persona.__init__(self, persona.nombre, persona.edad)
      self.sueldo = sueldo
```

Y ahora para instanciar un empleado tendrías que instanciar antes una `Persona`, tal como mostrabas tú mismo en tu ejemplo:

```
per_osvaldo = Persona("Osvaldo",39)
per_osvaldo.imprimir_datos()
empleado_osvaldo = Empleado(per_osvaldo,3000)
```

### Nota

Observa que haciéndolo de este modo pierdes ya la posibilidad de instanciar un `Empleado()` directamente, sin usar antes una `Persona()`. Es decir, ahora ya no podrías hacer `empleado_osvaldo = Empleado("Osvaldo", 39, 3000)`

En python no es posible definir diferentes métodos con diferentes tipos de parámetros, de modo que no puedes escribir dos métodos `__init__()`, uno que te admita una persona y un sueldo y otro que te admita un nombre, edad y sueldo.

Sin embargo puedes hacer algo equivalente, y es crear un método con un número arbitrario de parámetros para después distinguir dentro del método con cuántos ha sido invocado y el tipo de cada uno, para obrar en consecuencia. Por tanto podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
class Empleado(Persona):
  def __init__(self, *args):
     if len(args) == 2:
        nombre = args[0].nombre
        edad = args[0].edad
        sueldo = args[1]
     elif len(args) == 3:
        nombre, edad, sueldo = args
     else:
        raise TypeError("Número de argumentos incorrecto")
     Persona.__init__(nombre, edad)
     self.sueldo = sueldo
```

En este caso puedes llamarla con dos argumentos o con tres. En caso de que uses dos, se estará suponiendo que el primero es de tipo `Persona` y el segundo será el sueldo. Si pasas tres se estará suponiendo que son el nombre, edad y sueldo respectivamente.

Ni que decir tiene que este código es cada vez más feo, difícil de leer y de mantener. Y que además no es tan flexible al no permitirte especificar los parámetros en otro orden, basándose en su nombre (aunque también podría hacerse, añadiendo un parámetro adicional `**kwargs` y aún más condiciones en el interior, pero la fealdad del código seguiría aumentando).

Answer (score 0):

Sí, se puede hacer, aunque los casos de uso son **limitados**, y no te recomendaría hacerlo si estás aprendiendo, ya que **para eso existe la propia herencia**.

Primero de todo una corrección del código y es que en los métodos se pasan argumentos que se encuentran fuera de la clase, no atributos del propio objeto, por lo que `debe_impuestos()` quedaría así (le quitamos `self.nombre` como argumento ya que existe como atributo en la clase):

```
def debe_impuestos (self, nombre):
    if self.sueldo >= 3000:
        print(f"El empleado {self.nombre} tiene que pagar impuestos")
    else:
        print(f"El empleado {self.nombre} NO tiene que pagar impuestos")
```

Para implementar dicha solución debemos de:

1. Poner los argumentos por defecto de `Empleado` como `None`. Para que pueda existir un empleado que esté *vacio*
2. Crear un método que acepte un input de personas y fije las características de nuestro empleado vacio.

En este caso me creo el método `input_persona()`, el código quedaría así:

```
class Persona():

    def __init__(self,nombre,edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad

    def imprimir_datos(self):
        print(f"{self.nombre}, {self.edad}")

class Empleado (Persona):

    def __init__(self,nombre=None,edad=None,sueldo=None):
        Persona.__init__(self,nombre,edad)
        self.sueldo = sueldo

    def debe_impuestos (self):
        if self.sueldo >= 3000:
            print(f"El empleado {self.nombre} tiene que pagar impuestos")
        else:
            print(f"El empleado {self.nombre} NO tiene que pagar impuestos")

    def input_persona(self, cls):
        self.nombre = cls.nombre
        self.edad = cls.edad


per_osvaldo = Persona("Osvaldo",39)

per_osvaldo.imprimir_datos()

emplado_osvaldo = Empleado(sueldo=3000)
emplado_osvaldo.input_persona(per_osvaldo)
emplado_osvaldo.nombre
emplado_osvaldo.debe_impuestos()
```

El método `input_persona()` recibe una clase persona, que extrae el nombre y la edad y los pone como atributos de `Empleado`

### Bonus

Ahora tienes que pensar que sentido tiene, heredar de una clase persona, para luego no pasarle dichos parámetros. **¿Realmente es necesario, o se está complicando todo innecesariamente?** ya que lo puedes tener directamente desde la herencia.

Como he dicho antes, tiene casos de uso en los que puede ser necesario, pero si te encuentras aprendiendo sobre clases, yo no complicaría las cosas e iría poco a poco, aunque sin duda, ¡Está bien que mientras se aprende, uno se realice distintas preguntas y tenga diferentes ideas!